# iOS SDK Recording video without saving it to Photo Album

Tags: ios, video, photo-gallery

I need to save videos to Documents directory of my app but when I use UIIMagePickerController it automatically puts videos in Photo Album. Is there any workaround to this?

Edit:
I need to record the video in my app for feature processing, but I don't want to original video be saved in Photo Album. It's the feature of my application.

Comment: You could capture the emulator video with quicktime player

Comment: Hi. I wasn't referring to capturing video. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've just checked, and the application I'm working on at the moment that captures video with `UIImagePickerController` doesn't behave this way, and I didn't do anything to disable it.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this link](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/) which describes capturing a photo and saving it to the Documents directory.
After that check out [Apple's AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) which describes all the options to capture Media. I implemented the photo functionality from the 1st link. You might just need to change a few media types and be able to get the video saved to your Documents directory.